# why the user is not redirected

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am learning vuejs 3. And Vue Router.

I have this script in the "router.js" file (extract) :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
.....
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && loggedIn && !authorizedRoles.includes(roleId)) {
        console.log('forbidden')
        
        return {
          path: '/forbidden'
        }
        
      }
.....
```

When the connected user has not the necessary authorizations, then it must be redirected to the page "forbidden".
In my case, the conditions are KO. I see the message "forbidden" in the console , but there is no redirection.

If I go to the url "/forbidden", the page is correctly displayed.

What could be my problem ?

Comment: What about using https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#userouter and then initialize `const router =useRouter()` and redirection like this `router.push('/forbidden')`

Comment: Either not use `next` param, or call it. Without it being called, the navigation isn't completed.

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an old version of Vue router, which requires the user to call `next()` at least once. Try this code instead:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
.....
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && loggedIn && !authorizedRoles.includes(roleId)) {
        next({path: '/forbidden'})
      }
.....
```

If this doesn't work, try going with the named route instead:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
.....
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && loggedIn && !authorizedRoles.includes(roleId)) {
        next({name: NAME_OF_FORBIDDEN_ROUTE})
      }
.....
```

More information can be found [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#optional-third-argument-next).

Comment: I tried with your solution + a return after the next. But is the same, the user is not redirected.

Comment: Then I suspect your check is wrong. What is to.meta.requiresAuth?

Comment: for each route, there is (or not) this meta: { requiresAuth: true, authorizedRoles: ['DIRECTOR', 'TEACHER'] }

Comment: What if you instead try with the `next({name: NAME_OF_FORBIDDEN_ROUTE})`?